# C++ const std:string& security when passing to a third-party API

Tags: c++, string, security, stdstring

I have a third party API that expects me to pass a `std::string` by reference. It says it is accepting it with `const`. That pretty much means nothing because it can just cast the memory pointer to a non-const `char*` and modify my string.

Check the code below with an example.

Should I be concerned/suspicious about third-party APIs that ask me to pass a `const std::string&` (by const reference) instead of a `std::string` (by value)?

They told me it is because they want to avoid string copying as the strings can be long. Am I being paranoid or it makes sense?

```
class Blah {

public:
    static void testBlah(const string& s) {
        char* blah = (char*) s.c_str(); // cast away from const char*
        blah[1] = 'b';
    }
};

int main() {

    cout << "!!!Hello There !!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

    const string s = "xxx"; // NOTE THE CONST !!!

    Blah::testBlah(s);

    cout << s << endl; // prints "xbx"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) is important in C++. If a function says it takes an argument as a constant then you have to trust it. If it does something stupid like cast away the constantness and modify the data it will lead to *undefined behavior* and ruin the whole program. If that happens you should *loudly* shout (preferably publicly) at the creator of the function/library, and then promptly stop using it.

Comment: Don't execute code on our computer that you don't trust.

Comment: API requests CONST reference, so they probably are not going to change your string, but if you don't trust them, you can just make a copy of the string in your code and pass it to function.

Comment: C++ is inherently not type-safe so an API can theoretically do many nasty things to what you give it. However, if an API says it accepts a parameter by const reference you have to either trust it or do what @Sandro suggests. Being blunt, I do think you're being a bit paranoid about it.

Comment: @Sandro At least it was a good question this time :) Feel free to vote up :P

Comment: Was the argument _to avoid string copying as the strings can be long_ they gave me a valid one?

Comment: There is no protection whatsoever between a program and a function it calls. If you don't 100% trust the API with everything in your process, you are doing something horribly wrong and should consider isolating the API to its own process with a service wrapper.

Comment: @JacobsWright What is the actual problem? Does library really change the string value? If yes, why does it do it? Maybe there is some other bug (for example you you can write data to address pointed by dangling pointer, and it affects your string). Passing arguments by const reference is the common practice and it is not clear why you want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it in your own trusted class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Blah {

public:
    static void testBlah(const std::string& s)
    {
        char* blah = (char*)s.c_str(); // cast away from const char*
        blah[1] = 'b';
    }
};

class Safe_Blah {
public:
    static void testBlah(const std::string s)
    {
        Blah::testBlah(s);
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::cout << "!!!Hello There !!!" << std::endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

    const std::string s = "xxx"; // NOTE THE CONST !!!

    //Blah::testBlah(s);
    Safe_Blah::testBlah(s);

    std::cout << s.c_str() << std::endl; // now prints "xxx"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much doing what @Sandro suggested in the comments, right? Probably best just to clone the string when you pass it to the API.

Comment: How does that help? Suppose the API function searches accessible process memory for other copies of that same string data and modifies them too.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh dear, I hadn't thought of that... Please promise me you will only use your powers for good.

Answer (score 0):

An API that accept `const&` to an object is giving out a promise to not modify that object.  While, yes, the library may be nefarious and modify it anyway, doing so would be breaking the promise.  If the object you passed to it is defined as `const`, modifying it would be *undefined behavior*.  From the library developer perspective, *this would be very bad*.  Basically, the library devs would be inviting Chutulhu to come and break their users applications in arbitrary, random, unspecified and unpredictable ways.

When it comes to not trusting your library, you lose.  C++ API's are not "safe" in any conceivable way in terms of security from an attacker that controls a library you call.  When you call a function that is in a library, you pass control of execution over to that library.  That library will then have access to read and write all of the memory of your application and may if it so chose, replace the whole lot with it's own thing.  So if you're worried about a library doing evil stuff behind your back, you're pretty much out of luck.